# A riddle to solve What am I?

Tags: riddle

I come in many different colors, but today I am pink 
I am used to link things together 
I can be found inside of socks 
I can not be easily broken 
I can be purchased at different stores, but today I am at Walmart waiting to be used.

What am I?

Answer (score 5):

You might be

> **nails**

I come in many different colors, but today I am pink

> People can paint their nails different colors (yours might be pink today).

I am used to link things together

> You can nail things together, absolutely.

I can be found inside of socks

> Toe-nails

I can not be easily broken

> Hardware nails are very difficult to break

I can be purchased at different stores, but today I am at Walmart waiting to be used.

> You can buy nails at a lot of places - hardware stores for the fasteners, or a wide variety of cosmetic or drug stores etc. for false nails.
>  I have no idea about the specific reference to Walmart.